# WorkerRole throws 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-roles

I put id for finding file from Web Role to Worker Role using a socket, then I await when work is done, but socket throws an AggregateException with System.Net.Sockets.SocketException when process work in Worker Role. Log:

```
 Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
 Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 1 : Unhandled Exception:
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address 
 (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Why is error thrown?